# No animation when switching from fragment to activity and back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-animation

My main activity shows the content in fragments. If I press a button an other activity is starting with this line of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FragmentActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left).toBundle();
context.startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

So the new activity should slide in and the current activity should slide out. The problem is that the new activity is animated correctly. The current fragment doesn't have an animation.

**Update**

This solves the problem but i don't want to finish my activity.

```
finish();
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

**End of Update**

---

If I press the back button in FragmentActivity i've got another animation:

```
@Override
protected void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

Here again, only the animation of FragmentActivity is working (R.anim.slide_out_right). The animation (R.anim.slide_in_right) that should animate the Main isn't working.

This is what i'm trying to create: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Ho8vk61lVIU#t=67)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's not the beautifulest way but this is what i did to solve it:

**Fragment:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, FragmentActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(activity, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left).toBundle();
activity.startActivity(intent, bundle);
activity.finish();
```

**FragmentActivity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class); // the activity that holds the fragment
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).toBundle();
startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

The disadvantage might be to save everything in the activity that is holding the fragment.

Comment: `startActivity(intent, bundle)` is added in **API 16**. If you want for App compatibility, you can use `ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(), intent, bundle);`